# Multilingual site hreflang usage

Tags: html, multilingual

We have a global website showing unique content for each separate country. We have some problems about `hreflang` usage. Our site structure is like this:

Main portal:

```
example.com
```

If visitor from Germany, he will redirected to:

```
de.example.com
```

If this German visitor prefers to change language into English, he will open this page:

```
de.example.com/en
```

Each subdomain has different content, so `de.example.com` has content for Germany and `fr.example.com` has content for France and not the same. If the visitor from a country prefers to change the language, let's say German visitor from France, he will open:

```
fr.example.com/de
```

So for this situation how can we use the `hreflang` and `x-default` tags?

Answer (score 0):

The `hreflang` attribute (not tag) won’t help you at all. It is just declarative, indicating the language of the linked resource.

There is no `x-default` tag or attribute in HTML.

As regards to your problem, you have not described what the problem is. If it is about designing and implementing a multilingual site, as opposite to solving some specific problems with it, I’m afraid it is off-topic at SO due to being too broad.